# How can i make hover function work just over an image and not somewhere else?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: azure;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(6, 6, 6);
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.martin-scorsese {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0%;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  background-color: rgb(6, 6, 6);
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.text {
  font-size: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding-left: 450px;
}

.item {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: azure;
}


/* .the-weeknd {
    height: 500px;
    padding-left:50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
} */

.movie {
  color: azure;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-left: 550px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ticket Magnet</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Ticket Magnet</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/HTML/LPU%20Project/index2.html"><img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/01/05/arts/05martin-scorsese3/merlin_166494351_bd751ae1-3353-4343-bbd4-a20129ae3f1b-superJumbo.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp" alt="Martin Scorsese" class="martin-scorsese"></a>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/HTML/LPU%20Project/index2.html" class="item">Movies</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want my hover function just over Martin Scorsese's image, but my desired position of image is somewhere else (link below). When I move the image, the hover function works even when the cursor is not on top of the image. Please help me

I will apply same codes on weeknd's image, but later

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Bcg.jpg):

[image]

Comment: You should show a [mcve] that creates the layout shown in the image and has the described problem. Without it is not possible to say why your are that has the `:hover`  is to large.

Comment: well actually is clear that the :hover is triggered on the container.. but since there's some odd absolute positioned stuff, the only solution to correctly address that html scenario via css is doing something like: `.container a:has(.martin-scorsese){display: block;z-index: 1000;position: relative;} .container a:has(.martin-scorsese):hover + .overlay {opacity: 0.8;}` .. but `:has` isn't supported by FF so I had to give up and didn't post my answer. P.S.: those display:block and positioning stuff was added to make the `:hover` trigger on the `<a>` that gets used to reach the sibling `.overlay`

Comment: something more suitable could be achieved via js.. but I still think it would just be better to refactor the html in a way that would result friendlier to the classic css selector syntax

Comment: if `.martin-scorsese` was not a strict requirement, the selector to catch all links followed by `.overlay` would instead work and that solution would be working already. It's enough to remove `:has(.martin-scorsese)` from the previous rules selectors

Answer (score 0):

since there's some odd absolute positioned stuff, the only solution to correctly address that html scenario via css is doing something like: .container a:has(.martin-scorsese){display: block;z-index: 1000;position: relative;} .container a:has(.martin-scorsese):hover + .overlay {opacity: 0.8;} .. but :has isn't supported by FF so I had to give up and didn't post my answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Area Map. The syntax is as follows:

```
<map name="myMap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,10,20" href="somelink.html">
  <area shape="circle" coords="10,30,50,100" href="anotherlink.html">
</map>
```

You use the coords to define each area. You then can assign an ID to each area and make the hover items

Answer (score 0):

Due to the presence of unconventional absolute positioning elements, the exclusive recourse for appropriately managing the specified HTML scenario through CSS entails implementing a solution akin to the following: ".container a:has(.martin-scorsese){display: block;z-index: 1000;position: relative;} .container a:has(.martin-scorsese):hover + .overlay {opacity: 0.8;}". However, it is noteworthy that the pseudo-class ":has" lacks support in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).